# Why check boxes do not stayed checked as you scroll using flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flash, mxml

I've had problems using check boxes in data grids that are populated using dynamic data. The check boxes do not stayed checked as you scroll. How can i solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to persist the state of the checkbox using your item renderer and preferably your data model. You can find an example of how you could achieve [this blog post](http://www.returnundefined.com/2006/10/item-renderers-in-datagrids-a-primer-for-predictable-behavior).

Comment: Right. They key is that the datagrid reuses its item renderers, so you need to do a little extra work to manage their state.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem keeping cell state when scrolling using the Advanced Data Grid in version 3.0 that seems to have been fixed in 3.3. Try upgrading to 3.3. I think you'll also need to separately install the module that does graphs and charts; the new Advanced Data Grid is now found in that package.